# Proof of Anti-Foundation Axiom in Bourbaki Class Theory

Tags: set-theory

Anacona et al (2014) point out that Bourbaki Theory of Sets (1968) lacks the Foundation Axiom. Moreover, the authors remark that the expressive power of Bourbaki Theory of Sets is equivalent to the class theory of NBG.

Given that NBG is a conservative extension of ZFC and given the missing Foundation Axiom, I'm wondering if in Bourbaki Theory of Sets it is possible to prove the Anti-Foundation Axiom, which can be stated as either:

**(AFA$_{1}$):** Given any extensional binary relation ≺ on any set S, there exists a unique transitive set U such that (U,∈) is isomorphic (necessarily uniquely) to (S,≺).

**(AFA$_{2}$):** Every accessible pointed graph has a unique decoration.

I would like to ask you if someone could help me to see how the proof would work based on the axioms of Bourbaki Theory of Sets:

1. Axiom of Global Choice (in the syntactic manner of Hilbert's $\varepsilon$-operator)
2. Axiom of Extensionality
3. Axiom of Subsets
4. Axiom of Unions
5. Axiom of Ordered Pairs
6. Axiom of Infinity
7. Axiom of Replacement

I hope my hypothesis is clear. However, I acknowledge that this information might be not enough to formulate a proof, so please feel free to ask me any clarificatory question.

Comment: Since those axioms are consistent with the axiom of Foundation, they certainly don't disprove it - so a fortiori they certainly don't prove *any* antifoundation axiom.

Comment: I agree that those axioms are consistent with Foundation. But the Anti-Foundation is not just the negation of the Foundation Axiom, instead, it is equivalent to the Mostowski Collapsing Lemma without the well-founded assumption. So are you sure that from the fact that those axioms are consistent with Foundation it follows that they cannot prove Anti-Foundation? (Please, be patient with my questions, philosophy major here..)

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You have your implications twisted a bit: as you say, proving an antifoundation axiom is **stronger than** merely disproving foundation, but that's good for us. If you prove an antifoundation axiom, a fortiori you disprove foundation. So if you *don't* disprove foundation, then you *don't* prove any antifoundation axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they do not prove either of those antifoundation axioms (or anything else which could reasonably be called an antifoundation axiom).

This is because those axioms are consistent with the axiom of foundation. Therefore they don't *disprove* foundation. But any antifoundation axiom implies the negation of foundation - that's sort of the point - and so a fortiori your axioms can't *prove* any antifoundation axiom.

(Of course this all assumes they're consistent in the first place!)